# How to detect angle change in JS given a continuous touch input?

Tags: javascript, geometry, gesture

I'm making a game in JS where a user is given a prompt for a certain path, and then has to perform ("swipe") the same path via touch/pointer. If the path is close enough to the original prompt, then it's considered a success, otherwise it's considered a failure.

[image]

I'm now working on adding sounds to this experience. I want to be able to play a "swoosh" sound at the start of the input, and every time the user makes an angle larger than 90 (or some other arbitrary, theta, angle). So if the user draws a zig-zag, at the start of every zig and zag a new swoosh will be played.

The input is provided as an array of X/Y points, where new points get appended to it as the new input is provided (user continues moving finger/cursor).

Given this input, how can I detect when has the user just drew an angle larger than theta?

For example:

```
var points = [];
function onTouchInput(event){
     points.push({x: event.x, y: event.y});

     // this is the function I wish to implement 
     if(angleLargerThanTheta(points)){
       playSwoosh();
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to detect an angle in the lines drawn at all or to detect if *just right now* there was an angle? If the latter, how do you differ *just right now* from... say, 3 seconds ago? The user can touch slowly or fast, how do you determine this?

Comment: "just right now", at least in terms of UX, which means there's some leniency the delay (in the millisecond range).  My original thought was to look at the last "window" of N points drawn, and try to detect an angle there

Comment: If you can determine that the user has drawn 2 straight lines (or something that looks like 2 straight lines) you could use the starting and ending points to get the cosθ. If a and b are the 2 normalized vectors a=(x1, y1) b=(x2, y2) then a*b = (a)*(b)*cosθ. However, a*b = x1x2 + y1y2. Solve and find cosθ then make sure it is in the range you want.